# How to get record from table content as a data for popup form and displayed

Tags: php, javascript, html

the table content that i made as button for popup.
this popup has a function for input form and link to another page
here for the example of my table

```
 <div>
  <table width="1023" height="248" border="1">
    <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });" value="A1.8" /></td>
  </table>
 </div>
```

my popup form like this

```
<div   class="popup_window_css" id="sample">
<table class="popup_window_css">
<tr    class="popup_window_css">
<td    class="popup_window_css">
<div   class="popup_window_css_head"><img src="images/close.gif" alt="" width="9" height="9" />Aksi</div>
<div   class="popup_window_css_body"><div style="border: 1px solid #808080; padding: 6px; background: #FFFFFF;">
<form method="post" action="">
<table>
    <tr>
     <td> Werehouse </td>
    <tr>
     <td> Posisi</td>
     <td> <input type='text' name="p" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td> Product ID</td>
     <td> <input type='text' name="id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td> Product Name</td>
     <td> <input type='text' name="nama" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td> Production Date</td>
     <td> <input type='text' name="tgl" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2' align='right'>
         <input type='submit' value= 'Save'> 
         <input type='reset' value='Reset' />
         <input type='button' value='view' onclick=\"window.location.href='#';\"/>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div></div>
```

may be this screen shoot can help you to understand my problem

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwil302fdzhe0f5/New%20Picture%20%2829%29.bmp

**my Question**

how to get button value as data for popup form and automaticly shown in form "posisi"?

Comment: looks like you are indonesian ;), could you give us your popup_window_show function?

Comment: yes that's right I'm indonesian :)
this my popup function
https://www.dropbox.com/s/aqwltbyfzvqk7vg/popup-window.js

Comment: ic the simple solution, but not the best, set variable on javascript, and set your button value to it, and when the popup triggered, get that variable value to "posisi"

Comment: can you tell me more about you advise may be in code

Comment: hmmm some thing like this http://jsfiddle.net/JLExZ/

Comment: @Ricky oo i see but how to make that value can be record here
<input type='button' value='view' onclick=\"window.location.href='#';\"/>

Comment: you can use querystring, like 'yourtargetfile.html?posisi='+document.getElementById('posisi').value+'&id='+document.getElementById('id').value+'&etc' for building this url, you better set it to some variable and window.location.href=somevariable;

Comment: @Ricky yes the target i made in .php. on this page i call the database with "posisi's" value as parameter. we name of target as target.php. how to make link with this page include that value has been recorded and call back as parameter in target page SQL?

Comment: 'target.php?posisi='+document.getElementById('posisi').value+'&id='+doc‌​ument.getElementById('id').value+'&etc' , on php u can get that posisi value with $somevar1=$_GET['posisi'], $somevar2=$_GET['id'], etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tq for Ricky this the answer

```
<script>
    function setvalue(values) {
    document.getElementById('posisi').value = values;
}
</script>
<div>
    <table width="1023" height="248" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>

                    <input type="button" onclick="setvalue(this.value);" value="A1.8" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="popup_window_css" id="sample">
        <table class="popup_window_css">
            <tr class="popup_window_css">
                <td class="popup_window_css">
                    <div class="popup_window_css_head">
                        <img src="images/close.gif" alt="" width="9" height="9" />Aksi</div>
                    <div class="popup_window_css_body">
                        <div style="border: 1px solid #808080; padding: 6px; background: #FFFFFF;">
                            <form method="post" action="">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Werehouse</td>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Posisi</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type='text' name="p" id="posisi" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Product ID</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type='text' name="id" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Product Name</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type='text' name="nama" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Production Date</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type='text' name="tgl" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan='2' align='right'>
                                                <input type='submit' value='Save'>
                                                <input type='reset' value='Reset' />
                                                <input type='button' value='view' onclick=\ "window.location.href='#';\"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

you can cek here http://jsfiddle.net/JLExZ/

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTML5 data-attributes concept to set value in form data like
 and receive the data by JavaScript.

```
<div id="awesome" 
 data-hash="3e4ae6c4e30e50e4fdfc7bf439a09974">Some awesome data</div>

  var dataHashValue = jQuery("#awesome").data('hash');
     console.log(dataHashValue);
```